# Named parameter type for Array of Struct in biqquery

Tags: google-bigquery, nodejs-bigquery

I had a code like below

```js
        const changes = dto.data.map(d => `('${d.findingId}', '${d.status}', ${d.comment ? `'${d.comment}'` : null})`).join(',')

        const query = `
            MERGE \`${projectId}.dlp.result-status\`
            USING UNNEST([struct<findingId STRING, status STRING, comment STRING> ${changes} ]) changes
            ON \`${projectId}.dlp.result-status\`.findingId = changes.findingId
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT (findingId, status, modifiedAt, comment ) VALUES (changes.findingId, changes.status, '${now}', changes.comment)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE SET 
                    \`${projectId}.dlp.result-status\`.status = changes.status, 
                    \`${projectId}.dlp.result-status\`.comment = changes.comment
            ;
        `;

        const options = {
            query: query,
            // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
            location: 'US'
        };
```

but it was vulnerable to SQL injection, so I changed my code to use parameters

```js
        const changes = dto.data.map(d => ({ findingId: d.findingId, status: d.status, comment: d.comment }))

        const query = `
            MERGE \`${projectId}.dlp.result-status\`
            USING UNNEST(@changes) changes
            ON \`${projectId}.dlp.result-status\`.findingId = changes.findingId
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT (findingId, status, modifiedAt, comment ) VALUES (changes.findingId, changes.status, @now, changes.comment)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE SET 
                    \`${projectId}.dlp.result-status\`.status = changes.status, 
                    \`${projectId}.dlp.result-status\`.comment = changes.comment
            ;
        `;

        const options: Query = {
            query: query,
            // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
            location: 'US',
            params: { now: now, changes: changes },
            types: {
                now: 'STRING',
                // changes: [{ 'findingId': 'STRING', 'status': 'STRING', 'comment': 'STRING' }]
                // changes: ['STRUCT']
            }
        };
```

so important change is changing `changes` variable from concatenated string to array of objects and changing `USING UNNEST([struct<findingId STRING, status STRING, comment STRING> ${changes} ]) changes` to `USING UNNEST(@changes) changes`

When I ran this, I get this error

```
Parameter types must be provided for null values via the 'types' field in query options.
```

So I tried to add `types`, now I am stuck in how to add type for Array of struct, I tried these but no lock

```js
changes: [{ 'findingId': 'STRING', 'status': 'STRING', 'comment': 'STRING' }]
changes: ['STRUCT']
```

ps.
This is the type definition on Query
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this is only typing (ts) issue, I made it like this and worked (added `as any`)

```js
        const options: Query = {
            query: query,query.
            location: 'US',
            params: { now: now, changes: changes },
            types: {
                now: 'STRING',
                changes: [{ findingId: 'STRING', status: 'STRING', comment: 'STRING' }] as any
            }
        };
```

Comment: you can define type as `changes: ['STRING']` if your field is a simple array of strings. It is recommended to define the types in such scenarios, otherwise, it throws an error in case an empty array is provided in the params. (ps: hope this comment will help someone in future.)